# which activity will be opened via external link?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent

I'm deubgging an android app.

I have a bug that happens when someone open the app using http link:

i.e.

`http://appName.to/hsv8wrq6bd`

how can I see where is the entry point that this link opens and run my application?

Can i see it in `AndroidManifest`?

Answer (score 0):

Check for the Activity which declares http as the data scheme in AndroidManifest.

Comment: and then? enters its `onCreate` as intent?

Comment: Put a debug point in that Activity's onCreate. You should paste the stack trace from the logcat here for us to be able to help you further.